# Overridden CSS property can still be used to determine actual value?

Tags: css, font-size, css-specificity

In my browser, without any author or user styles, the `h1` `font-size` is 32px. I have been trying to figure out how the `h1` `font-size` results in an actual value of 24px, with the following HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="three.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
    <h1>My H1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

It looks like the user-agent font-size of `2em` overrides the 12px specified in the CSS. Even though it is shown as struck-through in Chrome Dev Tools (see below), it seems the 12px value is also used, because the `h1` not the default 32px. How can the 12px be overridden and still be used?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The selector `h1` is more specific than the `html` selector for the title tag. It has more priority that's why it's overriding your specified style.

**Why having 24px ?**

`font-size:2em` means twice the font size specified in the parent element (and here it's 12px) so you will have 2*12px = 24px. This is why the 12px you specified is also used.

To be more generic in the explanation we can say that **Xem means X times the size of the current font**. The current font depend of course on all the styles you applied (here you only have the one specified in the `html` tag).

You can read more [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

---

If you want to override the style you can simply specify :

```
h1 {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

or use `!important` selector like this :

```
html {
  font-size:12px!important;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. "twice the font size specified in the parent element" - do relative units like `em` and `%` always refer to the parent's property (if the property is one that is inherited)? I think this is the crux of my difficulty; I couldn't find it stated on this documentation https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade.

Comment: @flow2k yes it's always refere to parent. more generally it's the current **font-size** used, which means the font-size applied to this element if there is not font-size property specified, you can read more here too https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: @flow2k to make it simple. If you have a lot of CSS and in the end the font-size of h1 should be x. so if you specified 2em for this element it will be 2*x.

Comment: @flow2k as you can see in the link i sent `Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)`